Why does Debian ship a preconfigured firewall?
Recently I reinstalled Debian Testing (to become Trixie). After that, I couldn't use a network printer any more, which was resolved in this question.
This made me wonder:

Why is there a default firewall at all? What does it try to protect against?
Why should it block the mDNS ports? What would be dangerous about these?


I'm not sure Debian ships preconfigured firewall. you may have installed one specific firewall configuration, and a sensible default is: block everything originating outside your machine. -- I think Debian by default just remember the firewall settings between reboots (so also temporary hacks).

Are you using KDE by any chance?

At a guess, because they don't know whether or not your shiny new system will be directly accessible to the internet from the get-go, so they default to strict IP filtering policy. (Also calling it "a default firewall" as opposed to to a basic set of iptables instructions makes it sound more grandiose than it is)

@StephenKitt Yes, I am using KDE.
Thank you for the answers so far.

A default Debian setup doesn’t include a firewall (see Why does Debian come without a firewall enabled by default?). However, installing Debian testing with KDE currently sets up firewalld by default, which sets up a firewall blocking all incoming connections apart from DHCPv6 and SSH.
Technically, firewalld ends up installed because the KDE Plasma desktop recommends the plasma-firewall package, which recommends firewalld. Those dependencies are optional and can be removed. firewalld isn’t installed by default with KDE in Debian 12, but that’s because the plasma-desktop package specifies an invalid version for plasma-firewall!
Why would a firewall be useful by default? As described in the related Q&A linked above, Debian services ship with conservative configurations which only listen on local ports by default. But having a firewall can be useful as an extra layer of security: a misconfigured service won’t end up opening widely-accessible ports. On the other hand, a correctly-configured service also won’t be able to receive external traffic unless the firewall is also configured appropriately; so it’s a balance between security and convenience, and appropriate defaults would probably vary depending on the intended use of the system (a typical laptop or desktop, exposing no services, wouldn’t suffer from a firewall, and having one enables other types of protection, for example limiting outgoing connections; but a default firewall might be counter-productive on a server).
A default firewall setup can be made to work well by default, but that takes work, and integration across services (for example, installing a web server might open the relevant port in the firewall). Since Debian doesn’t enable a firewall by default, its packages don’t expect to have to configure one (which one anyway?), so the overall integration is less than ideal. In particular, nothing configures firewalld to let mDNS traffic in.

Could we stop recommended packages from being installed? At least should ask before installing plasma-firewall/firewalld (I would choose ufw). Do you know of any non-obvious reason KDE recommends plasma-firewall?

I suppose KDE recommends plasma-firewall because it’s part of Plasma since 5.21.0. Unfortunately there isn’t a way to choose ufw instead of firewalld — you can add it to the installation set by adding pkgsel/include=ufw to the installer kernel command line, but then it is installed in addition to firewalld.
